# Xml Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

```
[Serializable]
public class ProgressReport
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string F {get;set;}
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string I {get;set;}
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string O {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Кол-во операций")]
    public int CountOperations {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Кол-во актов")]
    public int CountActs {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Магическое число")]
    public long MagicNumber {get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Разработчик")]
    public string Developer
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}.{2}." this.F, this.I.Take(1), this.O.Take(1))
        }
    }
}

public static string ToXml<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) where T: class
{
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
    var path = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (var file = System.IO.File.Create(path))
    {
        xml.Serialize(file, src);
        file.Close();
    }
    return path;
}
```

`linq` запросом формирую необходимый мне объект, к нему применяю метод `ToXml()` и все почти работает, за исключением того что в xml файле нет `Developer`а

Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить.

Comment: сеттер добавить :)

Comment: @Dmitry а зачем там сеттер в данном свойстве я форматирую ФИО т.е. делаю Фамилия И.О.

Comment: без сеттера это вычисляемое поле

Comment: так по сути оно им и является, т.е. *сериализация* вычисляемых полей не возможна?! как тогда поступить в данном случае?!

Comment: ну сериализовать только те поля которые нужны, а вычисляемое поле на то и вычисляемое, оно после дисереализации нужно :)

Comment: @Dmitry в данном случае данное поле как раз то и нужно, на ум приходит только следующее: добавить в `Deleloper` `set`, где то раньше делать объединение приводить к нужному мне виду т.е. `string.Format("{0} {1}.{2}." this.F, this.I.Take(1), this.O.Take(1))`. Сериализацию в данном случае использую для построения `отчета`, обратной операции не планируется

Comment: ну собственно да, на ранней стадии делать слитие, например при установке одного из свойств F, I, O или свой атрибутик написать который будет сеттером рулить

Comment: Проблема именно в том, что для десериализации нужно присвоить значение полю. Если поле вычисляемое, вам нужна логика, которая в сеттере разберёт значение на кусочки и «распихает» их по полям `F`, `I`, `O`. Подумайте: как сериализация это сможет сделать за вас? Никак, ей неизвестно, как разбивать Developer'а на части.

Comment: Впрочем, я бы не заморачивался, и просто отказался от полей F, I и O. Дело в том, что схема «одно имя, одно отчество и одна фамилия склеиваются в этом порядке» валидна только для русского языка. В испанском всегда две фамилии, от отца и от матери. В английском нет отчеств. В исландском нет фамилий (а только отчества). В китайском фамилия пишется перед именем.  В немецком звание доктора наук и/или титул профессора являются официальной частью полного имени, и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Serializable]
public class ProgressReport
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Разработчик")]
    public string Developer {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Кол-во операций")]
    public int CountOperations {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Кол-во актов")]
    public int CountActs {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Магическое число")]
    public long MagicNumber {get;set;}
}
var users = db.Context.Users
            .Select(x=>new
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                F = x.F,
                I = x.I,
                O = x.O})
            .ToList() //Материализуем коллекцию
            .Select(x=>new
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Developer = string
                .Format("{0} {1}.{2}.", x.F, x.I.Substring(0,1), x.O.Substring(0,1))
            })
            .ToList();//Повторно материализуем в уже необходимом формате
```

дальше просто сериализую полученный объект

//здесьдальнейшая логика, join и т.п.

Спасибо @Dmitry, @VladD за подсказки в коментариях.

P.S. Фамилия Имя Отчество разделил на три поля потому что где то удобнее выводить в Фамилия И.О. если хранить в одном поле можно было бы конечно воспользоваться и `.Split()`, почему то на момент проектирования мне показалось логичнее хранить в разных полях, а сeйчас переделывать не вижу смысла

Comment: А зачем вам промежуточная материализация?

Comment: Просто вот так не пойдёт: http://pastebin.com/2i2z6GmC?

Comment: @VladD в качестве orm использую `entity-framework` он так не дает сделать, ругается
*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.* поэтому и делаю предварительную материализацию

Comment: А, понял. Ну тогда вместо внутреннего `.ToList()` можно использовать менее дорогой `.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @Bald56rus тут как бы и не нужен первый селект. зачем он там? достаточно написать `db.Context.Users.ToArray().Select(x=>new
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Developer = string
                .Format("{0} {1}.{2}.", x.F, x.I.Substring(0,1), x.O.Substring(0,1))
            }).ToList()`, если не предпологается юзать фичи списка, то лучше привести к массиву `ToArray()`

Comment: @Dmitry при помощи первого `.Select()` я материлизую необходимые мне поля в анонимный класс из которого потом делаю строку в необходимом формате, хотя можно и сделать как посоветовали Вы или VladD

Comment: @Bald56rus так достаточно только второй материализации на самом деле, попробуйте. **UPD** точнее достаточно второго селекта

Comment: @Dmitry Я пробовал, в комментарии Выше писал ошибку которая возникает при выполнении контактеции полей без предварительной материализации. может помочь предварительная материализация в массив как Вы писали Выше, но предварительная материализация нужна. Это связано с используемой `orm entity framework`

Comment: @Bald56rus да, я неверно выразился, конечно, не материализация а селект первый не нужен, достаточно второго

Comment: @Dmitry у меня только один тогда вопрос, зачем тянуть все поля перед первой материализацией, что это дает по сравнению с моим вариантом?!

Comment: @Bald56rus ну если полей много, то тогда да, лучше через анонимный сделать.